# SQL Server: Invalid Column Name. Msg 207

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error. I have a column named 'strSSN' in my Customers table. I tried inserting dummy data into my database and keep getting:

```
sg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 299
Invalid column name 'strSSN'.
```

Below is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE TCustomers (
     intCustomerID          INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strFirstName           VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
    ,strLastName            VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
    ,strAddress             VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
    ,intCityID              INTEGER         NOT NULL --FK .
    ,intStateID             INTEGER         NOT NULL --FK .
    ,strZip                 VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
    ,strPhoneNumber         VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
    ,strEmail               VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
    ,dtmDateOfBirth         DATETIME        NOT NULL
    ,strSSN                 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,intGenderID            INTEGER         NOT NULL --FK .
    ,intMaritalStatusID     INTEGER         NOT NULL --FK .
    ,intIncomeRangeID       INTEGER         NOT NULL --FK .
    ,intRiskAssessmentID    INTEGER         NOT NULL --FK .
    ,CONSTRAINT TCustomers_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intCustomerID )
)
```

and here is the dummy data:

```
INSERT INTO TCustomers (intCustomerID, strFirstName, strLastName, strAddress, intCityID, intStateID, strZip, dtmDateOfBirth, intGenderID, strPhoneNumber, strEmail, strSSN, intMaritalStatusID, intIncomeRangeID, intRiskAssessmentID)
VALUES                (1, 'James', 'Jones', '321 Elm St.', 1, 1, '45201', '1/1/1997', 1, '513-556-2150', 'JamesJones@gmail.com', '245-67-3456', 1, 3, 2)
                     ,(2, 'Sally', 'Smith', '987 Main St.', 3, 1, '45218', '12/1/2002', 2, '513-889-6587', 'SallySmith@gmail.com', '658-45-8720', 2, 2, 4)
                     ,(3, 'Jose', 'Hernandez', '1569 Windisch Rd.', 5, 1, '45069', '9/23/1998', 1, '859-986-2236', 'JoseHernandez@gmail.com', '223-78-6654', 1, 3, 1)
                     ,(4, 'Lan', 'Kim', '44561 Oak Ave.', 4, 1, '45246', '6/11/1999', 1, '513-522-4187', 'LanKim@gmail.com', '133-87-6422', 2, 2, 3)
                     ,(5, 'Tyler', 'Sims', '77 North Maple St.', 1, 1, '45219', '3/11/2001', 1, '513-522-4187', 'TylerSims@gmail.com', '145-27-7521', 1, 1, 5)
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af0565eaec866ad7b39afca3a6b923e9). Check the "is this thing plugged in" conditions, like being on the right server and the right database. (Incidentally, you want to be using an invariant and unambiguous format for date/time literals -- so `19970101`, not `1/1/1997`. And a "date of birth" really then ought to be a `DATE`, not a `DATETIME`. This also shows the folly of prefixing your column names with abbreviated types, since `dtm` then no longer fits...)

Comment: Sane here, works fine for me.

Comment: Weird... I just deleted all of my insert statements, ran the query to add the tables again, then re-added the insert statements....now everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: A lot of information you probably don't need to store. If you do, much of it should be stored **securely**. Difficult to believe much of this information is needed for a "customer". Dump that silly naming standard as well.